# why when pass void to int array it doesn't work my complier says "error: invalid initializer"

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm passing from void to int and I'm getting an error invalid initializer. as shown bellow

```
void *mergesort( void *value, void *value2){
 // my problem is in these two lines
    int *a[] = (int *)value;
    int *b[] = (int *)value2;

    int dotProduct =0;
    for (int i=0; i<10;i++){

//the operation of the dot product
    dotProduct += a[i] * b[i];  

    printf("\n  new  \n %d --- %d \n ",&a[i],b[i]);
                            }
    return NULL;
}

int main(){

int a1[20],b1[20],i, holdThd1 ,holdThd2 ;

 for( i=0; i<20;i++){

        a1[i] = rand() % 15;
        b1[i] = rand()%10;
}
 for( i=0; i<20;i++){

    printf("%d  --- %d \n", a1[i], b1[i]);
}

pthread_t thread1, thread2;
holdThd1 = pthread_create(&thread1,NULL, mergesort,((void*)&a1,(void*)&b1));
holdThd2 = pthread_create(&thread2,NULL, mergesort,(void*)b1);

pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
pthread_join( thread2, NULL);

printf("Thread 1 returns: %d\n",holdThd1);
printf("Thread 2 returns: %d\n",holdThd2);

return 0;
}
```

**I want to** create a thread that will calculate the dot product of the first half of the arrays a[] and b[].

I will be grateful to any suggestions.

Comment: `int *a[]` -> `int *a`

Comment: Read and memorize [The Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). The way you wrote it `int *a[]` means "`a` is an array of pointers to integer`, which is obviously not what you meant.

Comment: @kaylum thanks, do you know how can I pass more than a parameter to the thread without using struct ?

Comment: @sayo The only other way is to use a global variable but that is not a good way to do it in general. A pointer to a struct is the right way to do it. Do you have any issues with using a struct?

Comment: Don't add code into comments where it is unreadable. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64960239/edit) the post with any updates.

Comment: regarding; `printf("Thread 1 returns: %d\n",holdThd1);` and `printf("Thread 2 returns: %d\n",holdThd2);`  the variables `holdThd1` and `holdThd2` and the status of the call(s) to `pthread_create()`.   If they are not 0, then the call to `pthread_create()` failed.  The right way to use the returned status is:  `if( pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, mergesort, (void*)b1) ) { fprintf( stderr, "pthread_create for second thread failed\n");  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`  and similar for the first call to `pthread_create()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. demonstrates how to call `pthread_create()`, `pthread_exit()` `pthread_join()`
3. demonstrates how to write a `thread` function
4. demonstrates how to pass more than one value to a thread function
5. performs the desired functionality
6. avoids using 'magic' numbers, like 20
7. calculates the whole dot product, not just the first 10 elements
8. uses `size_t` for integers that will never be less than 0
9. demonstrates how to print a `size_t` variable
10. demonstrates how minimize the scope of variables, like `i` to the individual `for()` loop

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_ARRAY_LEN 20

struct parms
{
    int *array_a;
    int *array_b;
};


void *mergesort( void *arg )
{
    struct parms parameters = *( struct parms * )arg;
    int *a =  parameters.array_a;
    int *b =  parameters.array_b;

    int dotProduct =0;
    
    for ( size_t i=0; i<MAX_ARRAY_LEN; i++ )
    {
        dotProduct += a[i] * b[i];  //the operation of the dot product
        printf("\nDot Product for index %zu: %d \n ", i, dotProduct );
    }
    
    pthread_exit( NULL );
}


int main( void )
{
    int a1[ MAX_ARRAY_LEN ];
    int b1[ MAX_ARRAY_LEN ];

    struct parms parameters = { a1, b1 };
    
    for( size_t i=0; i<MAX_ARRAY_LEN; i++ )
    {
        a1[i] = rand() % 15;
        b1[i] = rand() % 10;
    }
    
    for( size_t i=0; i<MAX_ARRAY_LEN; i++ )
    {
        printf("%d  --- %d \n", a1[i], b1[i]);
    }


    pthread_t tid;
    
    if( pthread_create( &tid, NULL, mergesort, (void*)&parameters ) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "pthread_create failed\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    pthread_join( tid, NULL);
 
    return 0;
}
```

a typical run of the proposed code results in:

```
13  --- 6 
12  --- 5 
8  --- 5 
1  --- 2 
9  --- 1 
2  --- 7 
5  --- 9 
8  --- 6 
0  --- 6 
7  --- 6 
11  --- 8 
12  --- 9 
2  --- 0 
2  --- 3 
7  --- 5 
14  --- 2 
12  --- 8 
14  --- 7 
13  --- 6 
1  --- 2 

Dot Product for index 0: 78 
 
Dot Product for index 1: 138 
 
Dot Product for index 2: 178 
 
Dot Product for index 3: 180 
 
Dot Product for index 4: 189 
 
Dot Product for index 5: 203 
 
Dot Product for index 6: 248 
 
Dot Product for index 7: 296 
 
Dot Product for index 8: 296 
 
Dot Product for index 9: 338 
 
Dot Product for index 10: 426 
 
Dot Product for index 11: 534 
 
Dot Product for index 12: 534 
 
Dot Product for index 13: 540 
 
Dot Product for index 14: 575 
 
Dot Product for index 15: 603 
 
Dot Product for index 16: 699 
 
Dot Product for index 17: 797 
 
Dot Product for index 18: 875 
 
Dot Product for index 19: 877
```